# Finding a line parallel to another one, but going through a point not on the line?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to have two parallel lines of the form

$$x=x_0 + tv$$

where one line in vector equation form that has a point $x_0$ that does not lie in the line of the other line that it is parallel to?

Let's say I have two lines $j$ and $k$

J = (1,2,3) +t(1,2,3)

K = (a,b,c) +t(2,4,6)

Is it possible to find a point (a,b,c) that is in K but not in J?

Comment: Those are not vectors. They are lines.

Comment: Yeah, I seem to have used the wrong words, I have edited it. Does that mke more sense now?

Comment: It's still not really clear what you want to do. There are cases in which $J=K$, and other cases where $J$ and $K$ do not intersect. It depends on $(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite unclear what you are trying to ask.

The form $x=x_0 + tv$ does not describe a vector, it describes a line. More precisely, the set of all points $x$ which can be written as $x=x_0 + tv$ forms a line.

That said, if you set $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$, it is clear that the **line** described by $$x=(0,0,1) + t(2,4,6)$$ does not contain any point that is also in $$x=(1,2,3) + t(1,2,3)$$

Comment: sorry about the wording, was thinking of vectors and it ended up being typed. what I meant was that a line described using a point x0 and a direction vector v in n space. Sorry again.